# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imsave'

Tags: python

I read a csv file into a numpy array and then attempt to output this as a *.bmp file.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
image_array = genfromtxt('myfile.csv', delimiter=',')
print(image_array)
import scipy.misc
scipy.misc.imsave('outfile.bmp', image_array)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    scipy.misc.imsave('outfile.bmp', image_array)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imsave'
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could be the reason since your code hasn't been touched.

imsave is deprecated! imsave is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use imageio.imwrite instead.

Link: 
 https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html

Comment: if it has been deprecated, it has not been removed yet.

Comment: You're right.I thought the 1.2.0 version was out.Sorry my bad